# Automatically scroll PDF

Tags: pdf, raspberry-pi, scrolling, fullscreen, pdf-reader

I want to set up a raspberry pi which should present PDF files at full screen, which should automatically scroll. I have no problem in setting up a script that identifies the files to be viewed. However, I could not find any program that can be started and automatically scroll the PDF file I want. The only one which goes close to this is acroread, which however requires the intervention of the user to automatically scroll (i.e. I did not find any option to do this from the command-line.).

Any idea?

Comment: From [what I've read](http://www.adobe.com/uk/digitalimag/tips/phsel2slide/printable.html), If the PDF has been created as a slideshow, the PDF reader should automatically show it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the PDF, so I have to assume they are not slideshow.